# How to explicitly pop up the dialog to enter passphrase for SSH key?

Tags: gnome, ssh, 20.04, ssh-agent

I have a private SSH key which I use to login to remote server. When I start `ssh my.server` command in GNOME terminal, a dialog box pops up to enter the passphrase to unlock the key (see below - it's in Polish, however the language doesn't matter).

[image: SSH key passphrase dialog box]

That is ok, but I'd rather like to bring up this box right after I login to GNOME session, before I even attempt to make any SSH connection. What should I add to "startup programs" to achieve this?

Some time ago, on older Ubuntu version I added `ssh-add` to startup programs and it did the trick. However, when I try `ssh-add` now, it pops up the ugly dialog box shown below and not the one like above that I want. Which command brings up the above box?

[image: ssh-add dialog box]

Comment: Although I still didn't find a command to bring up that first dialog box, there is some workaround: after installing the ssh-askpass-gnome package, "ssh-add" displays a nicer dialog box than the second one...

Answer (score 0):

install package `ssh-askpass-gnome` this package will provide the binary
`/usr/lib/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass`

`ssh-add` and `ssh` will in somes cases use the binary from  **SSH_ASKPASS**

To test , open a terminal :

```
export SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/lib/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
ssh-add </dev/null
```

Comment: I have already written it in the comment above - it is not the same window as on the first picture, but the window provided by ssh-askpass-gnome looks better than the second one and is acceptable.
However, it's still not a full solution, rather a workaround.